# ¿Cómo puedo obtener las dos últimas palabras de una frase?

Tags: php

Necesito obtener las dos últimas palabras de una frase. En mi caso es del título de un producto de **Woocommerce**.

Sé que con `array_pop()` se obtiene la última, pero necesito las dos últimas.

```
$titulo = explode(' ', $product->get_name());
$variedad = array_pop($titulo);
```

Gracias.

Comment: `array_pop()` Extrae **el último elemento de un array** no la última palabra de una frase [según la documentación de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-pop.php)... desde mi punto de vista son dos cosas diferentes.

Comment: ¿2 años y todavía sin una óptima respuesta?

Answer (score 13):

`array_pop( )` **elimina** el último elemento del *array*, así que basta con llamarla 2 veces consecutivas:

```
$titulo = explode(' ', $product->get_name());
$variedad = [ array_pop($titulo), array_pop( $titulo ) ];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$frase = 'En un lugar de la Mancha de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme';

$array_palabras = explode(' ', $frase);
$longitud_array = count($array_palabras);

$ultima_palabra = $array_palabras[$longitud_array - 1];
$penultima_palabra = $array_palabras[$longitud_array - 2];

echo 'La última palabra es: ' . $ultima_palabra . '<br />';
echo 'La penúltima palabra es: ' . $penultima_palabra . '<br />';
```

Usando la función `explode()` necesitas acceder a los dos últimos índices del `array` resultante. Con la función `count()` podemos obtener el número de items que hay en el `array`, que al haber seleccionado como caracter separador el espacio, serán el número de palabras de nuestra frase. Con esos datos ya podremos acceder a los índices del `array` que necesitas.

Answer (score 3):

Que tal con [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php)

Obtener los dos últimos array:

```
$array = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'];

print_r( array_slice( $array, -2, 2 ) );

// Result:
Array
(
  [0] => tres
  [1] => cuatro
)
```

<kbd>**[Demo 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2923ed2affe696305a785467b10e8752ab1e2aa1)**</kbd>

> Observe que array_slice() reordenará y reinicializará los índices
>   numéricos del array de forma predeterminada. Se puede cambiar esta
>   comportamiento estableciendo el parámetro preserve_keys a TRUE.

Ejemplo:

```
$array = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'];

print_r( array_slice( $array, -2, 2, true ) );

// Result:
Array
(
  [2] => tres
  [3] => cuatro
)
```

<kbd>**[Demo 2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ce4ed423e08aa8d4af1510678e1310c501c13e1)**</kbd>

Comment: Esta es la que usaría yo, que conste :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Aportación para resarcir el despiste

Entendí que querías los dos últimos caracteres de la cadena, pero veo que necesitas las dos últimas palabras.

Como ya indicó @BlackSheep, lo puedes hacer con `array_slice`.

Para resarcir el despiste, comparto esta función que:

- recibe de forma dinámica la cantidad de palabras requeridas
- convierte la cadena a array mediante `str_word_count`... esta función nos da la ventaha de que no hay que *limpiar* la cadena de espacios en blanco por ejemplo.
- lanza una excepción si en la cadena hay menos palabras de las requeridas

#### Código:

<kbd>**[DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/UZUCS23081)**</kbd>

```
/*
* Obtiene n palabras de una cadena
*
* @param string $str la cadena original
* @param int    $count cantidad de palabras a extraer
* @param string $sep separador (opcional)
* @ return  Devuelve la cadena resultante
*/
function getLastWords($str, $count, $sep=" "){
    $mArray=str_word_count($str,1);
    if ( count($mArray) < $count ) {
        throw new Exception('La cadena tiene menos palabras de las solicitadas.');
    }else{
        $s=array_slice( $mArray, -$count ) ;
        return implode(" ",$s);    
    }
}
```

Hagamos algunas pruebas:

```
$s="      Lorem ipsum  dolor    sit amet    "; #Nótese que tiene espacios de más
var_dump(getLastWords($s,2));
$s="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var_dump(getLastWords($s,2));
var_dump(getLastWords($s,3));
```

---

```
#Probemos algo fake
var_dump(getLastWords($s,20000000));
```

**Salida cuando no hay excepción:**

```
string(8) "sit amet"
string(8) "sit amet"
string(14) "dolor sit amet"
```

**Salida excepción:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: La cadena tiene menos palabras de las solicitadas. in source_file.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 source_file.php(10): getLastWords('Lorem ipsum dol...', 20000000)
#1 {main}
  thrown in source_file.php on line 26
```

---

### La respuesta del despiste

Pensé que buscabas los dos últimos caracteres de la cadena. En ese caso esto es válido y lo dejo aquí por si le sirve al alguien.

Puedes usar [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) pasándole como segundo argumento un número negativo con la cantidad de caracteres, ya que cuando el número es negativo selecciona los caracteres empezando por el final de la cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```
$s="Lorem ipsum";
$lastTwo = substr($s, -2);
echo $lastTwo;
```

**Salida:**

```
um
```

**NOTA:**

Para este tipo de operaciones conviene crear una función que controle los eventuales errores que podrían ocurrir, por ejemplo, el Manual de PHP dice:

> Si la longitud del string es menor que start, la función devolverá
> `FALSE`.

Es una situación que hay que prever y controlar.

Answer (score 1):

**Buen día. Te propongo una solución más:**

```
$string = 'Esta es una frace con palabras';

$split = explode(" ", $string); 

//Aquí simplemente le pasas el número de la palabra que quieras obtener
$ultimaPlabra = $split[count($split)-1];
$penultimaPalabra = $split[count($split)-2]; 

echo '<b>Última Palabra: </b>'.$ultimaPlabra.'<br>';
echo '<b>Penúltima Palabra: </b>'.$penultimaPalabra.'<br>';
```

***Respuesta*:**

**Última Palbra:** palabras

**Penúltima Palabra:** con